# How do I retrieve the value of a label in a website?

Tags: c#, regex, web

I want to extract a label value from a website. I looked at the html source in Chrome and found the line:

```
<strong><span id="lbName">George</span></strong>
```

The label name lbName is unique in that request. But how do I extract the name "George" from this line? I looked at regular expressions, but so far it has only been if the string contains some pattern or not, which I already know it does.

```
    public static void GetName()
    {
        HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("Http://MyWebsite.com");
        myRequest.Method = "GET";
        WebResponse myResponse = myRequest.GetResponse();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(myResponse.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
        string result = sr.ReadToEnd();
        sr.Close();
        myResponse.Close();

        string sPattern = "lbName";
        // extract the value of lbName ?

    }
```

Comment: more than RegEx I think this should be done with a DOM parser, like Agility Pack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a library, [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). Use that. I'll add that if you are always looking at the same page, and you know the page won't change its format, you could simply use the `IndexOf` method and search for `<span id="lbName">`. Something like:

```
const string searchFor = "<span id=\"lbName\">"; // open marker
const string endSearchFor = "</span>"; // close marker

string result = "letters" + searchFor + "text" + endSearchFor; // Sample text, here put your text

int ix1 = result.IndexOf(searchFor);
if (ix1 == -1)
{
    throw new Exception();
}

ix1 += searchFor.Length;

int ix2 = result.IndexOf(endSearchFor, ix1);
if (ix2 == -1)
{
    throw new Exception();
}

string text = result.Substring(ix1, ix2 - ix1);
```

Comment: Thank you. In this instance, I know that the page structure will not change. But I will definitely look into Html Agility Pack too.

Comment: never throw pure Exception, use a derived class of it and pass some text in the constructor so it will be easy to understand what has happened

Comment: @Davide When I'm writing an example of 20 lines, I throw whatever I want. In RL, probably I wouldn't have thrown anything and I would have handled the error in some other way. Consider the `throw` to be placeholder for your error handling.

Comment: As an added note, I'll add that the piece of code I wrote could be written as a (quite simple) Regex, but I still prefer not to use RX becasue the day it fails, with a Regex you don't have anything to debug.

Answer (score 0):

The following Regular Expression should work:

```
[^<strong><span id="lbName">].*(?=</span><s/trong>)
```